# Android AsyncTask get result after finsih execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a class that extends AsyncTask

```
public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String response;

    public String getResponse(){
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         /* code */
         return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        response = aString;
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

In other activity, I create an instance of MyClass

```
 MyClass c = new MyClass();
 c.execute();
 response = c.getResponse();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response = " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However I got null on the response variable, maybe because the Toast was executed before the task finish. Could you give me the right way so I can get the result after the task finish?

Comment: Call Toast from AsyncTask.

Comment: Can u post thelogcat?

Comment: I need to get the result on the activity that create the instance

Comment: @ZZZ Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a class field for the result. The `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` delivers everything you need.

So you want to have a `String` back from the Task. In order to accomplish that you have to change the `Result` to `String`. Basically like this:

```
public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         /* do background stuff to get the String */
         return string; // the one you got from somewhere
    }
}
```

You also have to wait for the computation by calling the method `get()`.

```
String response = new MyClass().execute().get();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response = " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Read more about [AsyncTask#get here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get())

Comment: I don' think this works. Method `doInBackground` runs on background thread, but 'get()' run on UI thread, so both processes run in parallel and this does not guarantee that we can 'get' the right string returned from the processes in background

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` executes asynchronously, on a separate thread. Meaning that when you call `response = c.getResponse();` the task is still busy executing. You can either handle the result in `onPostExecute`, or use a `BroadcastReceiver`, or EventBus to notify your Activity that the task has completed.

Answer (score 0):

make one constructor in MyClass with Context of activity as a argument like below

```
 Context context;

 public MyClass(Context context){
    this.context = context;
 }

// make toast in onPostExecute
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      Toast.makeText(context, "response = " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

in another activity call asynctask like below

```
 MyClass c = new MyClass(YourActivity.this);
 c.execute();
```